# Reversing matrix rows in Prolog

Tags: matrix, prolog, reverse

I am trying to write a predicate which reverses all rows in a matrix using Prolog.

For instance the matrix [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ] should become [ [3,2,1], [6,5,4], [9,8,7] ].

My attempt so far is :

```
reverseRows([[H|T]|_],X):-reverse([H|T],X).
```

which reverses only the first row. How can I change the above to work for all rows ? Any assistance is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the predicate [maplist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3).

```
?- maplist(reverse, [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], Reversed).
Reversed = [[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]].
```

Other possible solution is:

```
reverse_rows([], []).
reverse_rows([Xs|Xss], [Ys|Yss]) :-
    reverse(Xs, Ys),
    reverse_rows(Xss, Yss).
```

Example:

```
?- reverse_rows([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], Reversed).
Reversed = [[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]].
```